# CampaignMonitor (PHP) Finding if an email is subscribed

Tags: php, api, email, newsletter

Using the CampaignMonitor API, I am able to subscribe, resubscribe and unsubscribe successfully, but I can't figure out how check if an email address is active, or unsubscribed.  The end goal, is basically if subscribed, echo an unsubscribe link, if not subscribed echo a subscribe link.

After digging around CMBase it appears that `subscribersGetIsSubscribed()` is what I need to target.  I've successfully been able to tap into the function and get the proper true/false response when I echo $cm->debug_response.  However, when I apply that into an if/else statement it doesn't work properly.

Example:

```
$result = $cm->subscribersGetIsSubscribed('test@test.com');
if ($cm->debug_response == "True") { 
    echo "active"; 
} else { 
    echo "not subscribed";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the CampaignMonitor forum answered, here is the result, which works properly...

```
$result = $cm->subscribersGetIsSubscribed('someone@example.com',$list_id);

if ($result['anyType'] == "True") { echo "active"; } else { echo "not subscribed";}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the if/else statement you're attempting?  Based on the documentation, it looks like this should work:

```
$result = $cm->subscribersGetIsSubscribed('someone@example.com');
if ($result == 'True') {
    echo 'active';
} else {
    echo 'not subscribed';
}
```

(Note that "True" is there a string literal, and not, as one would perhaps imagine, the true boolean value.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The result returned is an array, not a string.  I found out that the array key that holds the value is 'anyType'.  Thanks again for your efforts :)